# Rotate Jpeg in FFMPEG with transparent color

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to rotate an image and try to render it to MP4. But Output video is render with roted image with green background around it. My requirement is I need to changed green background to transparent.

Here is the command

```
ffmpeg -i Avideo.mp4  -i a.png -filter_complex "[1:v] rotate=-    
30*PI/180:c=black@:ow=rotw(iw):oh=roth(ih) [rotate];[0:v][rotate] overlay=40:10" -codec:a copy sample.mp4
```

Output is:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed c=black@ to c=0x00000000 and it worked for me.

```
ffmpeg -i Avideo.mp4  -i a.png -filter_complex "[1:v] rotate=-30*PI/180:c=0x00000000:ow=rotw(iw):oh=roth(ih) [rotate];[0:v][rotate] overlay=40:10" -codec:a copy sample.mp4
```

[The correct syntax is black@0 – Gyan]

```
ffmpeg -i Avideo.mp4  -i a.png -filter_complex "[1:v] rotate=-30*PI/180:c=black@0:ow=rotw(iw):oh=roth(ih) [rotate];[0:v][rotate] overlay=40:10" -codec:a copy sample.mp4
```

Both codes work. I couldnt find the correct syntax listed on the documentation page.
It would be helpful if the documentation page provided examples rather than say this does that.

Comment: The correct syntax is black@0

Comment: To do rotations also with jpg images, i also needed to add `format=rgba`, to support alpha channel.
Now it looks like: `format=rgba,rotate=a=$rotation:c=black@0:ow=rotw($rotation):oh=roth($rotation)`. Note that rotw(a), takes the radius in radians and not the size as suggested above.